# JxBrowser TimeoutException when waiting for main frame to load (invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame)

Tags: java, browser, load, loading, jxbrowser

I am using JxBrowser in a project. I am only working with local HTML files, and therefore using the following method to render my HTML files:

```
    public static void loadHTMLFile(Browser browser, String filename){
        String current = PathUtils.getCurrentDir();
        browser.loadURL("file:///" + current + "/some/path/in/my/project/resources/web/" + filename);
    }
```

In some of the cases I have to use the *invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame*-method since I have to initialize buttons which have to be loaded completely first.

An example from the official  JxBrowser website (https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013107-loading-waiting) looks like this:

```
// Blocks current thread execution and waits until http://www.google.com web page is loaded completely
Browser.invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame(browser, new Callback<Browser>() {
    @Override
    public void invoke(Browser value) {
        value.loadURL("http://www.google.com");
    }
});
```

In my case it looks like this:

```
public static void loadHTMLFileComplete(Browser browser, String filename){
    Browser.invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame(browser, new Callback<Browser>() {
        @Override
        public void invoke(Browser value) {
            loadHTMLFile(value, filename);
        }
    });
}
```

Nothing surprising so far I guess...

**Now comes the tricky part:**

The *invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame*-method is the problem:

1. the very first view (a login view) is loaded correctly with the *invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame*-method
2. after that my program times out (full exception below) when using the *invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame*-method again

   - for example when I click on the login button and want to be forwarded to the main view
3. there is a little hack which I found accidentally to get it working for the moment (now it gets creepy):

   - the timeout problem disappears when I load an online webpage in between e.g. google
   - it can also be with the *invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame*-method
   - this is how I do it

     ```
     public static void loadGoogle(Browser browser){
         Browser.invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame(browser, new Callback<Browser>() {
         @Override
         public void invoke(Browser value) {
             value.loadURL("http://www.google.com");

         }
     });
     ```

     }
4. here comes the timeoutException I mentioned earlier:

   ```
   -- Product name: JxBrowser
   -- Licensed version: 6.x
   -- Licensed to: 
   -- License type: Evaluation
   -- Generation date: 21.04.2019
   -- Expiration date: 21.05.2019
   -- License info: Single-user license
   -- Current date: 30.04.2019
   JxBrowser license valid.
   11:55:59 SCHWERWIEGEND:[0430/235559.671039:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(379)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser@6b9651f3
   11:56:49 SCHWERWIEGEND: Unexpected exception in DOMEventListener.handleEvent() method.
   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException 
   at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame(SourceFile:570)
   at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame(SourceFile:532) 
   at browserActions.PageLoader.loadHTMLFileComplete(PageLoader.java:15)
   at browserViews.OrderCreationView.loadView(OrderCreationView.java:21)
   at browserActions.ButtonInitializer.lambda$0(ButtonInitializer.java:26)
   at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.dom.internal.EventTarget$a.onMessageReceived(SourceFile:179)
   at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.q.a(SourceFile:1085)
   at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.r.run(SourceFile:69)
   at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.s.run(SourceFile:79)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
   ... 14 more
   ```

### To summarize:

**It does not work:**

- load the login view
- click the login button
- try to load the main view -> timeout

**It works:**

- load the login view
- click the login button
- load google
- directly after loading google (no time for the user to interact), load the main view -> no timeout

What is happening here :O ?

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JxBrowser is based on the Chromium engine and inherits its multi-process architecture. Each `Browser` instance is associated with at least one render process that handles DOM and JavaScript related functionality. When you navigate to a different domain, the Chromium engine creates a new render process and kills the old one. If you navigate within one domain, the render process remains the same.

From the call stack, I see that you try to load a URL from within a DOM listener. DOM listeners are invoked synchronously, so the render process remains blocked while the event is being processed by Java.

When you load a URL, e.g. google.com, everything works just fine, because a new render process is created and, as soon as the page is loaded, the `Browser.invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame` method returns control and the old render process is killed. However, if you try to load a `file:///` URL, the render process remains the same and the loading cannot start, because the render process is blocked by the `Browser.invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame` method called from a DOM listener, so you’ll get a deadlock.

In order to avoid this exception, you should not start synchronous navigation from within a DOM listener.

According to the call stack, you call the `loadView` method from a `DOMEventListener`. In order to avoid the deadlock you should call this method asynchronously, for example:

```
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.dom.events.DOMEvent;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.dom.events.DOMEventListener;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MyDomEventListener implements DOMEventListener {

    private final ExecutorService executorService;
    private final OrderCreationView view;

    public MyDomEventListener(OrderCreationView view) {
        this.view = view;
        this.executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(DOMEvent domEvent) {
        // Do not block the current thread and invoke the loadView method asynchronously.
        executorService.execute(view::loadView);
    }
}
```

In the `loadView` method you can load an HTML synchronously:

```
public void loadView() {
    Browser.invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame(browser, new Callback<Browser>() {
        @Override
        public void invoke(Browser browser) {
            browser.loadHTML("");
        }
    });
    initLoginButton();
}
```